# Issue with httpS call from external application to apache httpd web server

Tags: apache, ssl

Our application APIs are deployed in jboss container and access is enabled through apache httpd web server(2.4.48). External application is accessing our APIs via web server.

Web server access enabled with https using below configuration

```
<VirtualHost {SystemIP}:{somePort}>
ServerName abc.org.com
ErrorLog /www/home/logs/error_log
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /home/apache/http/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/apache/http/ssl/server.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/apache/http/ssl/ca-bundle.crt
...
</VirtualHost>
```

**server.key** contain private key, **server.crt** contain CA signed server certificate and **ca-bundle.crt** contain root and intermediate certificates and **external server certificate which is shared by external application team**.

When they try access our API via https (https://abc.org.com), client application is getting **PKIX path building failed**

From our apache server ssl log shows below error

```
[Mon Sep 06 05:34:54.321808 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 111:tid 12345] [client 160.82.161.2:46108] AH02008: SSL library error 1 in handshake (server ...)
[Mon Sep 06 05:34:54.321860 2021] [ssl:info] [pid 111:tid 140138261788416] SSL Library Error: error:14094416:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate unknown (SSL alert number 46)
```

But we are able to access https://abc.org.com from browser and certificates works fine.

What are we missing here? Where to add external application certificate into out web server ?

**Client side SSL log**

```
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-6, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
ExternalApplication-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
ExternalApplication-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 2E                               .......
ExternalApplication-1, called closeSocket()
ExternalApplication-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

2021-09-02 14:57:00.944 ERROR [ExternalApplication-1] c.d.p.AccountHolder - Error while processing AccountHolder serviceI/O error on POST request for "abc.com/apiPath": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Your API may not trust the server certificate and thus rejecting to negotiate with it. Pretty common in JAVA apps which do not have the remote server CA certificate in their trust list. SIDE NOTE: in 2021 you should just use SSLCertificateFile with both server certificate and CA's sorted from leaf to root and consider SSLCertificateChainFile deprecated as per the documentation.  SIDE NOTE2: If you really want an answer to your question you may have to show logs and debug messages from the client side too.

Comment: Client side SSL log added in question.

Comment: Well that confirms what I suspected "unable to find valid certification path to requested target" means just that, you need to add the CA's to the java cacerts or whatever trust storage your api uses.

Comment: @ezra-s Where to add ? Apache ca-bundle.crt (server side) or truststore used by external application(client side) ?

Comment: the problem is client side, not setver side, client refuses to negotiate with the server because it does not trust the CA that signed the server certificate. If this depended on a typical jdk installation I would look for a cacerts file inside jre/lib/security directory of the java installation. Import the public certificate chain of the Ca that signed the server cert inside the "cacerts" file, restart the app if it is inside an application server and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ezra-s pointed out correctly, there is issue with certificate loading in client side application. After importing certificates correctly, issue resolved.